# Who've or who have

Tags: grammar

When do I use *who've* and when *who have* when describing being successful in the past?
I googled *who've* and I found that most people prefer to use the longer "who have"

For example:

> I find coders **who've** been successful are usually biased in their views of how one should go about learning.

Is there a better way to state the sentence to describe success in the past?

Comment: There is no change in meaning when moving to a contraction.  It's simply done to make it easier to pronounce. Since it's only done to make it easier for lazy tongues it is viewed as informal and not appropriate for written text.

Answer (score 1):

The two are equivalent.  Use whichever one sounds best in the sentence.  Perhaps the "who have" form is more formal, but that's just my opinion.